# Is there a C# equivalent for C sprintf(result, "%5.5s", stringValue)

Tags: c#, formatting

When coding in C++, I can do something like:

```
sprintf(result, "%5.5s", stringValue);
```

This will ensure that the value printed is always 5 characters long, padding or truncating as required.

I find myself requiring the same feature in C# using String.Format:-

```
String.Format("{0,5}", stringValue);
```

Whilst this is fine for shorter values, it does not truncate longer values.

What is the best solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing dirctly equivalent, not with [#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txafckwd.aspx).

You can come close using `Substring` and `Math.Min`:

```
String.Format("{0,5}", stringValue.Substring(0, Math.Min(stringValue.Length, 5)));
```

Comment: I think this is the best option.
If I redo it like this:
`String.Format("{0,5}", StringValue).Substring(0, 5)`
I don't need the Math.Min().

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

I think **stringValue** is your string variable , if it so then the code will be

```
stringValue = (stringValue.Length < 5) ? stringValue  : stringValue.Substring(0,4);
```

Comment: @Ilya Ivanov I've modified the code. Now it won't through Exceptions

Answer (score 0):

There is not build in format to meet your need. Try to define custom extension methods and use it

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static string TruncateTo(this string str, int maxCharsCount)
    {
        if (str.Length > maxCharsCount)
            return str.Substring(0, maxCharsCount);
        return str;
    }
}
```

now you can

```
Console.WriteLine("{0,3}", "long long long value".TruncateTo(3));
Console.WriteLine("{0,7}", "short".TruncateTo(7));
```

will print:

```
lon
  short
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an extension method that should do what you want. You can change the max length and padding character to what you like, but the default is `5` and `-` respectively.

```
public static string ToCustomSprintF(this string initial, int max_length = 5, char padChar = '-')
{
     int len = initial.Length;

     if (len == max_length)
         return initial;
     else if (len < max_length)
         return initial.PadRight(len + (max_length - len), padChar); 

     return initial.Substring(0, max_length);  

}
```

You can then use it as normal

```
string str = "1234".ToCustomSprintF();
//output would be 1234-
```